# Equivalent of continue keyword in Java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
  for (final Prices ppr : prices) {
    if (!currency.getCode().equals(ppr.getCurrency().getCode())) {
      continue;
    }
    return ppr.getPrice();
  }
```

Can the code above be converted into Java stream code? I am getting an error with the `continue` keyword...

Comment: That `continue` is completely unnecessary in the example you've provided.

Answer (score 9):

```
return prices.stream()
     .filter(ppr -> currency.getCode().equals(ppr.getCurrent().getCode()))
     .findFirst()
     .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

Comment: Add that `currency` has to be final or effectively final.

Comment: you don't need to do .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new); the get() will throw the exception if there's no value anyway.

Comment: @george It's a matter of style. I prefer to avoid `Optional.get()` as it hides the optional-ness of the result.

Comment: @JohnKugelman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659181/adding-bigdecimals-inside-java-8-stream

Comment: John has a point here. It was even under discussion to deprecate Optionial.get() in Java 9. See http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-April/040484.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the provided answer you can also do

```
return prices.stream()
     .filter(ppr -> currency.getCode().equals(ppr.getCurrent().getCode()))
     .findFirst()
     .orElse(/* provide some default Price in case nothing is returned */);
```

instead of .findFirst().get() which returns the value which should not be empty. So it assumes there will be some data returned. With the orElse statement you can provide a default value in case nothing is returned.

Comment: I've corrected it. From the docs get() Returns:the non-null value held by this Optional otherwise throws an exception. It assumes the value is non null though so the OP needs orElse to provide a default result