# Adding Bigdecimals inside java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, bigdecimal

I would like to know if one way is more effecient than the other. Is there a better java 8 way to do the following operation ?

java 8 way

```
BigDecimal total = entries.parallelStream()
    .map(poec -> BigDecimal.valueOf(poec.getQuantity().longValue() * poec.getAdjustedUnitPrice().doubleValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Normal Java 7 way

```
    for (final EntryConsumed poec : entries) {
      total = total.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(poec.getQuantity().longValue() * poec.getAdjustedUnitPrice().doubleValue()));
    }
```

Comment: you can have a test. I think Java 8 parallel stream will more efficient.

Comment: Why are you collecting to a List before-hand? You don't need to do that.

Comment: @Tunaki : that was a brilliant point.

Answer (score 1):

You have some redundant code in your Java 8 solution. It can be simplified to:

```
BigDecimal total = entries.parallelStream()
            .map(poec -> BigDecimal.valueOf(poec.getQuantity().longValue() * poec.getAdjustedUnitPrice().doubleValue()))
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

As for performance, you can calculate this yourself by benchmarking the two solutions.